# How to avoid subclass without use of final Keyword in Java

Tags: java

```
final class AbsTest {}

class BTest extends AbsTest {}
```

How to prevent creation of subclass(es) without using the `final` keyword?

Comment: So... why are you trying to do this? as pointed out in the answers so far, there are ways for certain conditions, but final was created for a reason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the few options

- Create Private Constructor
- make each method final, so people can't override them. You avoid accidental calling of methods from subclass this way. This doesn't stop subclassing though.
- put check into constructor for class:

  if (this.getClass() != abc.class) 
    {
          throw new RuntimeException("Subclasses not allowed");
    }

***But***  `final` *is provided to solve such problem I must say*, *so better to go with* `final`!!!

Answer (score 1):

> In above code how to prevent to create subclass without use of "final"
>   keyword

You can declare private constructors to avoid creation of Object.

```
private AbsTest() {

}
```

Comment: This won't work if both are inner classes and they share same parent, in that case using `final` is the only option.